# SQL Server: How to get current date time in YYYYMMDDHHMISSMSS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need the current date time in the format `YYYYMMDDHHMISSMIS`

Example:

```
20110723233747607
```

By using the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` or `getdate()` functions, we can retrieve the current datetime into `2011-07-23 23:37:47.607` format. If I use `REPLACE` and `CONVERT` functions to remove the "-" and ":" characters, then I get the value into

```
Jul 23 2011 11:37PM
```

...format. But I need the current date time as `20110723233747607` to use it for my another purpose.

My SQL query is:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),'.','')
```

output: `Jul 23 2011 11:37PM`

So how can I get the current date time in my required format? Pls help.

Comment: And you never thought to try adding REPLACE functions for whatever other characters you want removed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
select replace(
       replace(
       replace(
       replace(convert(varchar(23), getdate(), 121),
       '-',''),
       '.',''),
       ' ',''),
       ':','')
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why you need to use so many REPLACE() functions. Usage of functions really reduce the execution time. I used two CONVERT and one REPLACE function below.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) + REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 114),':','')
```